Is there a way to do this in web developing or a library that can do this invert/inside rounded corners?
Invert rounded corners
I want to make invert/inside rounded corners into my project with just 1 div is there any way to do this? Or any library that can do this trick?
failed corners
I already tried using 2 div but the result is not what i expecting

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
